# Cannot start debugging visual studio 2013

Tags: c#

So I'm getting this error message whenever I try to debug my code. Doesn't matter what project I have open it's the same error message. What have I done wrong for it to be this way?

> Visual Studio cannot start debugging because the debug target 'c:\users\xxxxx\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\HängaGubbe1.001\bin\Debug\HängaGubbe1.001.exe' is missing. Please build the project and retry, or set the OutputPath and AssemblyName properties appropriately to point at the correct location for the target assembly.

Comment: Have you cleaned and rebuild your project? Have you followed the suggestions in the error message?

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516333/debug-target-is-missing

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if your error is related to the one I had but in my case, I had two different Visual Studio versions installed in my computer. So I upgraded my current to service pack 1(solution that actually worked by a user here on Stockoverflow). Or you can set output location to your desktop. Sometimes changing saving location works. And sorry if my answer didn't help. I am new to here and also learning.