# Visual studio cannot start debugging - Monogame

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2013, monogame

Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition seems to be giving me the error:

[Picture of the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOwZ4.png)

Now, I am aware others have had this problem.

Sites I have looked at that did not help:

[Cannot start debugging visual studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21841181/cannot-start-debugging-visual-studio-2013)

[Debug Target Is Missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516333/debug-target-is-missing)

(There are other links too, cannot post more than 2 though.)

I verified and changed the output path, I also went to: 
Build -> Configuration Manager and Checked the `Build` box.
I also tried right-clicking the project and selecting `Set as StartUp Project`.

It could possibly be something I am overlooking, but I'm not too sure... I also apologize if this question is sloppy, I'm a little intimidated to ask here.

This is only so far happening in the Monogame Windows Project template.

Comment: Does this issue only occurs on this specific Monogame Windows Project or all Monogame Windows Projects have this issue? And please check your Visual Studio Community 2013 version to make sure it has installed latest update.

Comment: @Wendy-MSFT, I just updated Visual Studio 2013 to the latest update and tried creating new projects using the Monogame Windows Project template and it still gave me the same error. As for other Monogame templates, I cannot create them as those give other errors unrelated to this one.

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete the bin\debug folder.
2. Clean the solution
3. rebuild the solution

Answer (score 0):

The Monogame project templates in Visual Studio needs [Monogame SDK](http://www.monogame.net/downloads/) installed.

Since a new Monogame project also has this issue, I suggest you uninstall Monogame SDK from Control Panel -> Programs and Features and reinstall this project template.

After uninstalling Monogame SDK and before reinstalling, please repair your Visual Studio 2013 to make sure there doesn't have any installation problem. And then reinstalling Monogame project template.

Comment: Hm, I attempted to repair VS (not sure if it was repaired though, but when I checked the only things that failed to install were SQL-related things) and I have reinstalled the Monogame SDK. I have looked at the project's .csproj (Never done this before) manually and saw that the output paths of the Debug and Release configurations *seemed* to be swapped, so I manually fixed it, this leads now to an error of "Error while trying to run project: Could not load file or assembly 'Game' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.".

Comment: Following link shows the .csproj in my Visual Studio 2013 for Monogame project, which is fine in my side: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AkHKK8SV6besg2qgmmDJcgBvun87 Please check whether there has any difference with yours. In addition, since you have repaired your Visual Studio and reinstall Monogame SDK, please use http://aka.ms/vscollect  to gather the VS and .Net Frameowrk installation logs. After using it, you will find vslogs.cab from %temp% folder. Please upload the file to Onedrive and share the link here.

Comment: The only difference between my .csproj and yours were the <DefineConstants> and <ProjectGuid> line contents, I changed the DefineConstants line to match yours but not the ProjectGuid as I heard it should not be changed, or does it? Anyways, after using the exe you provided me it seems to generate a number of files before closing suddenly, I could not find a vslogs.cab , only a vslogs.zip which seemed to be in an unknown format or damaged.

Answer (score 0):

*Check your code and make sure you **aren't** missing a curly bracket **anywhere**. If one was accidentally deleted, moved, or misplaced, it causes this error among MANY others depending how critical the placement of the curly bracket is in your project.*

^

I just recently had this problem in a project I was working on. I had highlighted to delete a section of code, and it took out a curly bracket with it. Unnoticed by myself, it took me a few days to finally realize that's what happened.

You won't get an error from the bracket missing, so it's stupid in itself and impossible to find at times.. but I had 51 errors, 7 warnings, and that "can't start debugging because the debug target is missing" error when I attempted to run the program, after the curly bracket went missing.

It's not to say that you might not have another issue going on that is causing this, but the curly brackets can wreak havoc if they aren't precisely placed. So it's worth checking into that before getting too extreme in options to "fix" the start error.

Good luck!