# How can I set output path and assembly name in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#

I am coding this in Visual Studio 2010 and I have Windows 8 ... but the error is to set output path and assembly name properties appropriately to point at the correct location for the target assembly ... How can I set these to remove error and run this code?

Code is :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace RectangleApplication
{
    class Rectangle
    {
        public double width;
        public double length;

    }

    public double GetArea()
           {
    return width*length;
}

    public void Display()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Lenght:{0}", length);
    Console.WriteLine("Width: {0}" , width);
    Console.WriteLine("Area: {0}" , GetArea());
}

    class ExecuteRectangle  
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
            r.length = 3.5;
                r.width =4.5;
            r.Display();
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the _exact_ error message, at which moment it occurs and what you have tried to resolve it. See for example [Debug Target Is Missing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516333/debug-target-is-missing).

Comment: error message after compiling this code is

" please set OutPath and assembly name properties appropriately to point at the correct location for the target assembly "

i tried to upload image of it ...but can't load here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to the following:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;

    namespace RectangleApplication
    {
        public class Rectangle
        {
            public double width;
            public double length;

            public double GetArea()
            {
                return width * length;
            }

            public void Display()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Lenght:{0}", length);
                Console.WriteLine("Width: {0}", width);
                Console.WriteLine("Area: {0}", GetArea());
            }
        }

        public class ExecuteRectangle
        {
            public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
                r.length = 3.5;
                r.width = 4.5;
                r.Display();
                Console.ReadLine();

            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that you had placed the GetArea and Display functions outside the Rectangle class.

Comment: now code is fine but i am getting this error after compiling it              " please set OutPath and assembly name properties appropriately to point at the correct location for the target assembly "

Comment: Try and create a new Project, replace the content of your "Program.cs" into the code above and try and build it again.

It could be some settings in general that have been corrupted.