# Unavailable projects in solution

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a VB.NET solution and when opened with VS 2010 it loads perfectly with all the items/forms but there are no project files and so the option to start debugger is disabled.

See screenshot:

[image]

Any help on this?

Comment: I can see what you mean now, thanks. As a suggestion, right click the solution and create a project. Under that project you can add forms by right clicking the project and then adding existing files. You could browse to where the solution items are and add them to the project. Worth a try.

Comment: Thanks in advance. I'm going to try that.

Comment: Hi there, I added a new project and I'm getting this error 'Visual studio cannot start debugging because the debug target 'D:\xxx\solution2\xxx\bin\debug\xxx.exe' is missing. When I check the path, I find xxx.vshost.exe. Any idea?

Comment: Can you build the project?

Comment: Not yet, I'm getting 'Builed Failed' and also 'Rebuiled All Failed'

Comment: Is that due to the same error or for other compile errors? It won't build until all compile errors have been resolved.

Comment: It is due to the same error, all codes are okay

Comment: Is this the same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516333/debug-target-is-missing