# Can't implement a basic decision tree using Accord.Net framework

Tags: c#, visual-studio, id3

I'm trying to learn how to implement decision trees in C#. I'm really new to this subject and I'm using the example given on the Accord website to learn.
My code is all copied from the website but visual studio keeps telling me:
visual studio cannot start debugging because the debug target is missing.
My code is this one:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Accord;
using Accord.MachineLearning.DecisionTrees;
using Accord.MachineLearning.DecisionTrees.Learning;
using Accord.Math;
using Accord.Statistics.Filters;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            DataTable data = new DataTable("Mitchell's Tennis Example");

            data.Columns.Add("Day", "Outlook", "Temperature", "Humidity", "Wind", "PlayTennis");

            data.Rows.Add("D1", "Sunny", "Hot", "High", "Weak", "No");
            data.Rows.Add("D2", "Sunny", "Hot", "High", "Strong", "No");
            data.Rows.Add("D3", "Overcast", "Hot", "High", "Weak", "Yes");
            data.Rows.Add("D4", "Rain", "Mild", "High", "Weak", "Yes");
            data.Rows.Add("D5", "Rain", "Cool", "Normal", "Weak", "Yes");
            data.Rows.Add("D6", "Rain", "Cool", "Normal", "Strong", "No");
            data.Rows.Add("D7", "Overcast", "Cool", "Normal", "Strong", "Yes");
            data.Rows.Add("D8", "Sunny", "Mild", "High", "Weak", "No");
            data.Rows.Add("D9", "Sunny", "Cool", "Normal", "Weak", "Yes");
            data.Rows.Add("D10", "Rain", "Mild", "Normal", "Weak", "Yes");
            data.Rows.Add("D11", "Sunny", "Mild", "Normal", "Strong", "Yes");
            data.Rows.Add("D12", "Overcast", "Mild", "High", "Strong", "Yes");
            data.Rows.Add("D13", "Overcast", "Hot", "Normal", "Weak", "Yes");
            data.Rows.Add("D14", "Rain", "Mild", "High", "Strong", "No");

            // Create a new codification codebook to 
            // convert strings into integer symbols
            Codification codebook = new Codification(data, "Outlook", "Temperature", "Humidity", "Wind", "PlayTennis");


            // Translate our training data into integer symbols using our codebook:
            DataTable symbols = codebook.Apply(data);
            int[][] inputs = symbols.ToArray<int>("Outlook", "Temperature", "Humidity", "Wind");
            int[] outputs = symbols.ToArray<int>("PlayTennis");

            // Gather information about decision variables
            DecisionVariable[] attributes =
{
            new DecisionVariable("Outlook",     3), // 3 possible values (Sunny, overcast, rain)
            new DecisionVariable("Temperature", 3), // 3 possible values (Hot, mild, cool)  
            new DecisionVariable("Humidity",    2), // 2 possible values (High, normal)    
            new DecisionVariable("Wind",        2)  // 2 possible values (Weak, strong) 
    };

            int classCount = 2; // 2 possible output values for playing tennis: yes or no

            //Create the decision tree using the attributes and classes
            DecisionTree tree = new DecisionTree(attributes, classCount);

            // Create a new instance of the ID3 algorithm
            ID3Learning id3learning = new ID3Learning(tree);

            // Learn the training instances!
            id3learning.Run(inputs, outputs);

            string answer = codebook.Translate("PlayTennis", tree.Compute(codebook.Translate("Sunny", "Hot", "High", "Strong")));

            Console.WriteLine("Calculate for: Sunny, Hot, High, Strong");
            Console.WriteLine("Answer: " + answer);

        }
    }
}
```

P.S. I'm using visual studio community 2017.

Comment: Does your project build? Have you set the startup-project?

Comment: Yes it builds fine, and I have set the start-up project... but I still get the same error

Comment: I suggest you to create a new project from scratch and rebuild it. The sample code builds and runs with no problem, **EXCEPT**, that you need to replace this line `data.Columns.Add("Day", "Outlook", "Temperature", "Humidity", "Wind", "PlayTennis");` with individual calls, like this: `data.Columns.Add("Day");`
            `data.Columns.Add("Outlook");`
            `data.Columns.Add("Temperature");`
           `data.Columns.Add("Humidity");`
            `data.Columns.Add("Wind");`
            `data.Columns.Add("PlayTennis");`.

Comment: Your question and problem does not have any relation to the Accord.net and ID3 algorithm's. But is a general problem that could have happened with any other code in your project.

Answer (score 1):

From [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516333/debug-target-is-missing)

> 1. Make sure that output path of project is correct (Project > Properties > Build > Output path)
> 2. Go in menu to Build > Configuration Manager, and check if your main/entry project has checked Build. If not, check it.

This seems to fix the problem for most users.

Comment: it didn't solve the problem for me but thanks anyway