# How do we specify a debug target to Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, fortran, visual-studio-2019

here is my program

```
program hello
    print *, "Hello World!"
end program hello
```

and it says to me

> visual studio cannot debug because a debug target has not been specified

Comment: Probably related to [this answer on C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9540064/8506658), Fortran is not related to the problem, it's your VS project that hasn't been properly configured.

Answer (score 2):

The way this normally happens is that you chose the incorrect project type - for example, a library instead of executable. If your project is properly building an EXE and you still get this error, right click on the project, select Properties. Then on the Debugging property page set the `Command` property to `$(TargetPath)`. Otherwise, create a new project of the correct type (for example, `Console Application`