# Visual Studio cannot find .exe file in the projet

Tags: vb.net, exe, project

I am confronting the following error:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEdFi.png]

I need help please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Debug Target Is Missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516333/debug-target-is-missing)

Comment: Do a Rebuild Solution after you verify where the project will compile

Comment: It's not working.

Comment: Have you actually looked in that folder to see whether that file is there? "it's not working" it's never of any use to anybody.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by excluding a project form. All forms used in the project are cloned. The truth is I don't know if this influences anything, or there is a paid version of Visual Basic that doesn't limit the number of duplicate forms to use. The project did not create the executable file when trying to run it. I had to create a new form and duplicate the others from this one so that it would continue to work. Thanks a lot.